# Wowza - Purpose of the dynamic port.

Tags: wowza

What is the purpose of the **port 48234 in Wowza** ?. For every restart, this port is keep on changing. Not sure, why/where this port configuration is present and what is the purpose

tcp        0      **0 0.0.0.0:48234**               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7609/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1935                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7609/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8083                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7609/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8086                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7609/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8087                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7609/java

If someone have any idea on this, pls share here.

Comment: What traffic do you see? My wild guess is the licensing

Comment: I couldn't see any traffic on this port. May be licensing port. Do you have any link that wowza says the dynamic port belongs to Licensing.?. As I have tried to find out, but unfortunately I couldn't identify that.

Comment: What version of Wowza are you on?  Grab the [latest](https://www.wowza.com/pricing/installer) and see if this still occurs.